# How to set columns titles row size in GridView

Tags: c#, .net, gridview, webforms

Trying the set the size of the columns titles row to the size as the other rows

[image]

```
               <div style="width:1000px; height:350px; overflow:scroll;">
                   <asp:GridView ID="GridBox1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Comic Sans MS" Height="350px" Width="980px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridBox1_SelectedIndexChanged">
                       <Columns>
                          <asp:CommandField SelectText="Select" ShowSelectButton="True" />
                       </Columns>
                       <rowstyle Height="35px" />
                       <alternatingrowstyle  Height="35px"/>
                       <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CCCCFF" />
                   </asp:GridView>
               </div>
```

Comment: can you put your code in the post as a code block I can't read the picture well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right.
The GridView is set to be 350px high.

Normally your grid would then evenly distribute the cell heights of each row. But because you set 35px height on your datarows, the ‘rest pixels’ are used in the headerrow.

If you want the headerrow to be also 35px, you should add:

```
<HeaderStyle height=“35px” />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem caused because I've set the Height in the GridView.

Had to remove this

```
 Height="350px"
```